# Facebook Share - Get just shared comment/description

Tags: facebook, get

I was looking for and I am interested is there any way to get just shared facebook description using maybe fb.ui/fb.init or some other way?

EXAMPLE:  [IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2hBc.png)

After the share I could get the description on my website let's say this way:

> document.write('The description you've shared!')

So maybe one of you know how to do it or maybe someone knows how to figure it out. I am really looking forward for it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the feed/share dialog using `FB.ui`, you can specify a callback function that receives the new post's `post_id`. Then using the `post_id`, you can retrieve the contents of the post by using an `FB.api` call. So a basic example:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
    caption: 'An example caption',
    }, function(response){
        FB.api(response.post_id, function(resp) {
            document.write(resp.description);
        });
    }
);
```

I'm not sure if all the fields are right, but that should give you the basic idea. Let me know if this makes sense :)

Feed and Share Dialogs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Post Object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/